# Ubuntu 20.04 installation on a USB flash drive

Tags: boot, usb

I installed a full Ubuntu 20.04 installation on a 32 GB USB Sandisk flash drive and restarted the computer, but the following log appeared on the screen.

```
illOa
jacnine
nk 5: 8600000005'
0.139837]  mce:   [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef873cO MISC f8a0000086      " 0.139902]  mce:   [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1608218334 SOCKET 0
APIC 0 microcode 26 
0.541303]  Initramfs unpackg failed: Decoding failed 
[11.799739]  usb 3-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[23.063740] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3t error -62 .
[24.415740] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[25.035750] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[25.043785] usb usb3-portl: unable to enumerate USB device
Gave up waiting for root file system device.   Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) ——— - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)    -
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; Is /dev) 
ALERT!    uuiD=559aaa74-c3b3-4ec6-b274-fffe85e!42cc does not exist.   Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox vl.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1)builtinshell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands

(initramfs)_
```

How can I solve it? Or will I have to do installation again?

Comment: What type of PC hardware is this? Is the USB drive attached to a hub or directly to the computer?

Comment: Yes it was directly attached to computer usb port.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to install another way.

### Extracting and cloning from an image file

Have a look at [**this link**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS), that can help you install by extracting and cloning from an image file of an installed Ubuntu system. This system can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and it uses the free Linux drivers for graphics and wifi.

Use one of the following links to download the compressed image file,

- more stable:

  [dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-06.img.xz](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-06.img.xz)
- or with faster upgrading of program packages (using the 'proposed repository')

  [dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-07_with-proposed.img.xz](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-07_with-proposed.img.xz).

Check that the download was successful, that the md5sum matches the listed entry in [this file](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/md5sum.txt.asc), with your eyes 'manually' or with the following command line,

```
<<<'89b3cd5206a1ce0e6b569cf276e04d7f  dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-06.img.xz' md5sum -c
```

or

```
<<<'ac00ae810b120d7b7dfca4d995593fbf  dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-07_with-proposed.img.xz' md5sum -c
```

when in the same directory as the compressed image file.

### If there are problems

- If you have new nvidia graphics, you may need the boot option `nomodeset`, and later on (when the installed system is running), you can install a proprietary nvidia driver.
- If you need a proprietary driver for wifi, you can connect via wired internet (ethernet) and install a suitable proprietary driver for that purpose.
- See also specific detailed tips for installing this system to a USB drive at [**this link**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).

### In the future

Please check at the linked web site, if there is some newer image file of the whole Ubuntu system (with file size greater than 1 GB),

[phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/?C=M;O=D)